# Adding .png watermark on .jpg

Tags: php, gd, watermark

I have line: `imagejpeg($this->image, $file, $quality);`

How can add on this image watermark.png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the image ([`imagecreatefrompng`](http://php.net/imagecreatefrompng))
2. Copy it onto the jpg ([`imagecopy`](http://php.net/imagecopy) or other copy functions)
3. Save the resulting jpg
4. ?????
5. PROFIT!